# Calcular coluna

Tags: mysql

Eu quero calcular a coluna Rodadas automaticamente, pra pegar os últimos 10 jogos do time entendi? não coseguir fazer isso com SELECT, acho que tem que ser na criação da tabela...

Esse é o code da criação da tabela e o select:

```
create table Sweden (   
    TimeID varchar(40) not null,
    Rodada int,
    Mando varchar(7) not null,
    Feitos int not null,
    Sofridos int not null,
    Feitos1T int not null,
    Sofridos1T int not null,
    Feitos2T int as (Feitos - Feitos1T),
    Sofridos2T int as (Sofridos - Sofridos1T),
    Total int as(Feitos + Sofridos),    
    DadoInserridoEm date
);
select 
    TimeID as 'Time',
    sum(if(Rodada > 0,1,0)) as 'Rodadas',    
    round(avg(Feitos1T),2) as 'Feitos 1st' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos1T),2) as 'Sofridos 1st',    
    round(avg(Feitos2T),2) as 'Feitos 2nd' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos2T),2) as 'Sofridos 2nd',        
    round(avg(Feitos),2) as 'Feitos' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos),2) as 'Sofridos',    
    round(avg(Feitos1T) + avg(Sofridos1T),2) as 'Media 1st' ,   
    round(avg(Feitos2T) + avg(Sofridos2T),2) as 'Media 2nd' ,
    round(avg(Total),2) as 'Total',        
    SUM(if(FT80min > 0,1,0)) as 'ft80min',
    SUM(if(Total >= 9,1,0)) as 'Over 9 asi',
    SUM(if(Total >= 10,1,0)) as 'Over 10 asi',
    SUM(if(Feitos > Sofridos,1,0)) as '1x2', -- Teve mais cantos que o adversárioo
    max(DadoInserridoEm) as 'Inserido Em'
from Sweden
group by TimeID;
```

(Sou iniciante)

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta consulta utilizando sql, você deve utilizar a função `limit` em conjunto com a função `order by`.

Desta forma a sua consulta seria:

```
SELECT 
    TimeID as 'Time',
    sum(if(Rodada > 0,1,0)) as 'Rodadas',    
    round(avg(Feitos1T),2) as 'Feitos 1st' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos1T),2) as 'Sofridos 1st',    
    round(avg(Feitos2T),2) as 'Feitos 2nd' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos2T),2) as 'Sofridos 2nd',        
    round(avg(Feitos),2) as 'Feitos' ,
    round(avg(Sofridos),2) as 'Sofridos',    
    round(avg(Feitos1T) + avg(Sofridos1T),2) as 'Media 1st' ,   
    round(avg(Feitos2T) + avg(Sofridos2T),2) as 'Media 2nd' ,
    round(avg(Total),2) as 'Total',        
    SUM(if(FT80min > 0,1,0)) as 'ft80min',
    SUM(if(Total >= 9,1,0)) as 'Over 9 asi',
    SUM(if(Total >= 10,1,0)) as 'Over 10 asi',
    SUM(if(Feitos > Sofridos,1,0)) as '1x2',
    DadoInserridoEm as 'Inserido Em'
FROM Sweden
GROUP BY TimeID
ORDER BY DadoInserridoEm DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Para aprender mais sobre como funciona o [limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) e o [order by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) veja na documentação oficial.

Comment: Desse jeito eu vou pegar os últimos 10 time, daria certo se cada time tivesse sua própria tabela... acho que esse foi meu erro, colocar os times em uma tabela só. Vlw ae